# Button with image in ttk

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a button with an image in tkinter.ttk with the following code:

```
img = PhotoImage(file="image.png)
btn = ttk.Button(root, image=img)
btn.pack()
```

with this code I get the imge on the button but I get it with the background and border of the button.
How can I have only the image and not the border and background?

[image: Here's what I mean]

Comment: Why not use the standard tkinter button if you don't need any of the styling provided by ttk?

Comment: Because then I have to write .ttk in all the widget of the code and I don't like having to write it

Comment: What you say makes no sense. You only have to change one line of code to use a tk button rather than a ttk button.

Comment: yeah but how about using tk buttons and ttk buttons?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use them both in the same application.

Comment: let's say I have 500 buttons, I want one of them to be like I said before and 499 to be normal, and I use `from tkinter.ttk import *`

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't do `from tkinter.ttk import *`, and that's not what your question shows. If that's what you want to do, you just need to import tkinter or just the `Button` from tkinter in a way that lets you reference it. Personally I think it's a best practice to do `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import ttk` so that you are explicitly everywhere about which library you're using. That way it removes all confusion. Bottom line is that tkinter imposes no restrictions on using both. Any restrictions are self-imposed.

Comment: is there a way to style it?